# HTML loading state only works with one button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I work with Bootstrap and i want to add several buttons with the loading state-"effect". But the problem is that the loading state only work with one button. Can anyone explain me why and maybe show me an working example?

HTML:

```
 <td>
   <input type="button" id="fat-btn" data-loading-text="Einschalten..." class="btn btn-success" onclick="l1_on();" value= "einschalten" />
   <input type="button" id="fat-btn" data-loading-text="Ausschalten..." class="btn btn-danger" onclick="l1_off();" value= "ausschalten" />
 </td>
```

JS:

```
 $('#fat-btn')
  .click(function () {
    var btn = $(this)
    btn.button('loading')
    setTimeout(function () {
      btn.button('reset')
    }, 3000)
  })
```

Comment: change id to class and it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IDs are supposed to only return one element.

Try with class names, it's more correct, adding another class for example 'loadable' will do the trick:

```
<input type="button" id="fat-btn" data-loading-text="Einschalten..." class="loadable btn btn-success" onclick="l1_on();" value= "einschalten" />
   <input type="button" id="fat-btn" data-loading-text="Ausschalten..." class="loadable btn btn-danger" onclick="l1_off();" value= "ausschalten" />

 $('.btn.loadable')
      .click(function () {
        var btn = $(this)
        btn.button('loading')
        setTimeout(function () {
          btn.button('reset')
        }, 3000)
      });
```

I would encourage to don't repeat ID attributes on documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `btn` class like:

```
 $('.btn').click(function () {
     var btn = $(this);
     btn.button('loading');
     setTimeout(function () {
         btn.button('reset')
     }, 3000);
 });
```